# check value in more than one inserted object Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

What I want to achive is check if hours count in day is higher than 24.

For example:
I've got entity hour with fields:

```
Integer id;
LocalDate date;
Integer hours;
```

Now I use post method to add new objects for example:
I add first one:

```
id - 1
date - 22.08.2018
hours - 10
```

I add second one:

```
id - 2
date - 22.08.2018
hours - 10
```

I add thrid one (hours count is now higher than 24 so I need an exception to be thrown )

```
id - 3
date - 22.08.2018
hours - 10
```

What I already have:

```
<sql>
    ALTER TABLE hours_worked ADD CONSTRAINT more_than24h CHECK (hours &gt;=0 AND hours &lt;= 24)
</sql>
```

But this one only checks if I'm not adding more than 24 at once.

Comment: you can use constraint to check OTHER rows - you need trigger here

Comment: sorry, but I'm totally out of mind, can you show me a sample?

Answer (score 1):

you can use constraint to check OTHER rows - you need trigger here, example for insert:

```
t=# create table i (id int, h int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into i values(1,10),(1,10),(2,23);
INSERT 0 3
t=# create or replace function fi() returns trigger as $$ begin
if (select sum(h)+NEW.h > 24 from i where id = NEW.id) then
raise exception '%','over 24 for '||NEW.id;
end if;
return NEW; end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# create trigger ti before insert ON i for each row EXECUTE PROCEDURE fi();
CREATE TRIGGER
t=# insert into i values(1,1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into i values(1,1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into i values(1,1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into i values(1,1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into i values(1,1);
ERROR:  over 24 for 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fi() line 3 at RAISE
```

of course you need similar for UPDATE

Comment: this isnt what I expected but gave me an ideas how I can do it, thanks.